# How to set animation speed of ScrollToAsync(Element, ScrollToPosition, Boolean)?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use ScrollToAsync(Element, ScrollToPosition, Boolean) method but its animation speed is a bit slow. Can I set animation speed?

```
   scrollview.ScrollToAsync(secondpage, ScrollToPosition.End, true)
```

Comment: I have never tried the follow but here is what I would do: Use custom animation https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom/ and try to animate scroll position. Publish here if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Easing class https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Easing/ to do you animation on an element, so when you scroll you animate the element to which you are scrolling here is a sample on how to animate

```
    var stck = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20),
    WidthRequest = 250,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    Opacity = animate ? 0 : 1
};

stck.FadeTo(1, 1000, Easing.CubicIn);
```

Comment: I need to use ScrollToPosition.End because of that I don't use fade animation.